# Moving files from one directory to another in the same remote server

Tags: php, symfony, ftp

I'm developing an application with Symfony2, and my users get to look at their folders (located in alfresco) but at a certain point some files need to be moved from one folder to another.

I tried `ftp_rename` but didn't have much luck with it. I could rename a file's name with it but I couldn't move it from one location to another.

I tried looking at the alfresco docs but didn't find anything helpful because I'm developing an api and I can't use Cmis Js.

Comment: *"i didn't have much luck with it , i could rename file's name with it but i couldn't move it from one location to another."* - Why, what did you try? Show us!

Comment: i read in Php website that the function can "move" files that's why i used that syntax with  $source = /alfresco/data/archives/ and $destination =/alfresco/data/input/

Comment: Small orthographical and puctuation fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ftp_rename` can rename/move a single file only. You cannot use it to move all files in a directory to another.

So you have to:

- list all files in the source directory, e.g. using the [`ftp_nlist`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php).
- call the `ftp_rename` for each, one-by-one.